# How to insert tiffs into slides with google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, tiff, google-slides

I'm trying to insert tiff images (and other unsupported formats, e.g. bmps) into google slides from drive using google scripts. I am using the following code:

```
imageID = '';
slideID = '';

function insertImageFromDrive() {

  var image = DriveApp.getFileById(imageID);
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(slideID);
  presentation.getSlides()[0].insertImage(image);

}
```

but am getting the error 'Exception: The image you are trying to use is invalid or corrupt.' from 'insertImage'.

Is there a workaround or other method for this?

Thanks.

Comment: "_unsupported formats_" really means unsupported formats.

Comment: Yes, I asked if there's another method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the TIFF and BMP image files and put them to the Google Slides.

Unfortunately, in the current stage, these image files cannot be directly put to the Google Slides. In this case, it is required to convert them to another format that can be put to the Google Slides. In this answer, I would like to introduce this method.

#### Sample script:

This script uses Drive API. So when you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
var imageID = "###" // Please set the file ID of the image file.
var imageUrl = Drive.Files.get(imageID).thumbnailLink.replace(/\=s\d+/, "=s1000");
var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(slideID);
presentation.getSlides()[0].insertImage(imageUrl);
```

and also, you can use the following script.

```js
var imageID = "###" // Please set the file ID of the image file.
var imageUrl = Drive.Files.get(imageID).thumbnailLink.replace(/\=s\d+/, "=s1000");
var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getBlob();
var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(slideID);
presentation.getSlides()[0].insertImage(image);
```

- When `thumbnailLink` is used by modifying the query parameter, the images of various mimeTypes can be converted to PNG format. This method uses this situation.

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works well for adding tiff images, the only issue is the images are quite compresses and detail is lost. Is there any way to lessen the compression? Also, is this code inserting the thumbnail of the image?

Comment: @sp2 Thank you for replying. In that case, `1000` of `=s1000` is the width of the converted image. So when this value is large, the image size is large. But I'm not sure whether this could resolve your new issue. So please test it. I apologize for this.

Comment: that's not problem. Changing `s1000` to different values does indeed change the image size, but it does not change the compression level. Furthermore, it does not seem to be possible to increase image size beyond `1000`. This code is still useful to me though, so thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the `.insertImage()` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertimageblobsource):

> Inserting the image fetches it from the BlobSource once and a copy is stored for display inside the presentation. Images must be less than 50MB in size, cannot exceed 25 megapixels, and *must be in either in PNG, JPEG, or GIF format.*

So TIFF's and BMP's are not supported directly.  However, we can convert between some image types using `File.getAs()`, which will attempt to convert a file format. As [documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getascontenttype):

> For images in BMP, GIF, JPEG, or PNG format, any of 'image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', or 'image/png' are also valid.

So try changing the line in question to

```
var image = DriveApp.getFileById(imageID).getAs('image/jpeg');
```

This should work for BMP's but likely won't work for TIFF's.  In the case of TIFF's you may have to use some third-party conversion tool.

Comment: Sorry, first part of my original answer was incorrect.  Edited to remove that part.

Comment: Yes, this works for adding bmps, thanks!